# MATLAB Implementation of Karplus Strong algorithm with filter function?

Tags: z-transform

I want to implement following function: `y = ksalgrithm(x, alpha, M, Nout)` where

- `x` is the input vector with length `Nout`
- `alpha=0.99`
- `Nout` is the length of the output vector.

The algorithm should do the convolution of $y[n]=(h_1\star x)[n]$, where $h_1[n]$ is the inverse of the $z$-transformation of $H_1(z)$. The input signal should have values $l = T_0 \cdot f$ and filled up with zeros until the vector has the length of `Nout`.

I want to use MATLAB's [`filter`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html).

```
Nout = length(x);
M = T_0*fs;
alpha = 0.99;
function [ y ] = ksalgorithm( x, alpha, M, Nout )
    syms z;
    H = filter(1,1-alpha*z^(-M),x);
    H_1 = 1/(1-alpha*z^(-M));
    h_1 =  iztrans(H_1);

    y = zeros(x);
    ...
```

I get always this error?

```
Undefined function 'filter' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
Error in ksalgorithm (line 23)
    H = filter(1,1-alpha*z^(-M),x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter(b,a,x)` function of MATLAB does not operate on **symbolic** variables. Your line of code

```
syms z
```

creates a symbolic variable `z`, in MATLAB environment, and later
you feed this variable into the `filter()` function through its second argument in this line:

```
H = filter(1,1-alpha*z^(-M),x);
```

where the `filter(b,a,x)` function, in this mode is expecting a **numerical** coefficient vector $a[k]$ associated with the DT system that's defined by the coefficient vectors $a[k]$ and $b[k]$.

In order to get the `filter()` function working, replace the symbolic expression

```
1-alpha*z^(-M)
```

with the numerical one, given integer `M` and real `alpha`

```
a = [1 zeros(1,M-1) -alpha]
```

Comment: ok. what I have to do instead?

Comment: let me edit and show it